# PHPExcel write string to each cell

Tags: php, arrays, string, phpexcel

i just using PHPExcel and want to write  a string from name to each cell starting L14 and goes to right (M14,N14,..), my code is below :

```
$length = strlen($name)

for ($i =0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    $char = $name[$i];
    $rowID = 14;
    $columnID = 'L';
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID,$huruf);
    $columnID++;
}
```

But the result is only last character that write to L14, any one have a clue for my problem?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Because you're resetting $rowID and $columnID **inside** the loop (PHP 101):

```
$length = strlen($name)

$rowID = 14;
$columnID = 'L';
for ($i =0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    $char = $name[$i];
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue($columnID.$rowID,$huruf);
    $columnID++;
}
```